# how to route any user controller in '/' in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning laravel and i saw people creating a route like
`Route::get('/user','homeController@fetchSocialLinks');`

the homeController has these code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class homeController extends Controller
{
 public function fetchSocialLinks()
 {
   $test= DB::select('SELECT * FROM `social_links`');

   return view('/',compact('test'));
 }

}
```

i want to get the $test variable in ('/') i.e. my root address page .
Can any one tell me the right way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO ... views are not URLs they are names ... what 'view' do you want to return and how are you trying to use `$test` which will be an array of records

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest reading the Laravel documentation to get acquainted with how routes, controllers, models and views work https://laravel.com/docs/8.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the view method, the first argument to pass is a page, i.e you have a blade page named welcome.blade.php, so that function fetchSocialLinks will render a view and you can pass to it a variable like the following code :

```
return view('welcome',['test'=>$test]);
```

Some good practices suggest you to name that method "index", concerning the routes you have to know that something changed since Laravel 7, you have to declare your controller like that :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\homeController;

Route::get('/', [homeController::class, 'fetchSocialLinks']);
```